# Combination of `sleep` and `pause` command

Tags: batch-file, input, sleep, simultaneous

Ok, after seeing crazy stuff being completed in so little code, I have high hopes this is possible.

Pretty much, I want to use the `pause` command normally, however, if the user doesn't input anything for a specified duration of time, it automatically continues.

In pseudo code:

```
(sleep %sleep-time%&Echo Pass)1>0 & pause
```

I thought at first I could do this using `start /b` to create a process that echoed input while being paused i the current thread, but that could cause problems if the user **does** input something.

#### Bonus

What would be really cool is if the errorlevel would be changed based on whether the user inputted something, or if the `pause` command timed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `timeout`:

```
timeout /T 60 >NUL
```

This will sleep your script for 1 minute, or unless the user hits a key.

Comment: no need to do so, but even Monas pseudo-code works with a little modification: `(timeout /t 60 & echo d)>nul|pause`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem TimedPause.bat - Antonio Perez Ayala

if "%1" equ ":PausePart" goto PausePart
if "%1" neq "" goto begin
echo TimedPause.bat seconds
echo/
echo Wait for given seconds or until user press a key
echo At end, the presence of keyPressed.txt file indicate the cause of exit
goto :EOF

:begin
set seconds=%1
start "" /B "%~F0" :PausePart
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FO CSV') do (
   set PausePart=%%a
   goto TimePart
)

:TimePart
   ping -n 2 localhost > NUL
   if exist keyPressed.txt goto :EOF
   set /A seconds-=1
if %seconds% gtr 0 goto TimePart
taskkill /PID %PausePart% /F > NUL
goto :EOF

:PausePart
del keyPressed.txt 2> NUL
pause
echo %time% > keyPressed.txt
exit
```